# Re-submitting incomplete code test after interview

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, developer, test, code

I am currently interviewing for a software engineer position at a company I am really excited about. I recently had a technical interview with two engineers and have a team fit interview still to come. Prior to the technical interview I was given a code test, part of which involved a framework that I do not know well. I did my best to work through it but was not able to get a complete solution for that section.

In the interview they praised the work that I had finished and gave me some constructive feedback on the incomplete section. After the interview I studied the unfamiliar framework some more, went back to the code challenge, and was able to complete it.

I'm considering pushing the changes to the test repository and emailing the engineers, thanking them for the code feedback they gave me. My concern is that this will come off as awkward or pandering. The interviewers did genuinely give me very insightful feedback, both positive and negative. Of course, I'd also like to try and make up for not finishing the code test by demonstrating that I am a quick and motivated learner.

Any advice on how I should follow up would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, go for it.  Don't make a big deal about it.

Comment: As someone who does a lot of interviews, I think this is a fine idea. Do it. Like the others said, short and professional.

Answer (score 8):

So right now you're waiting to hear back from them about the job?  Or has it been long enough that you're fairly sure they won't call?

In either case, **I would highly recommend doing it.**  Just set your expectations appropriately, is all.  Keep the email short and professional if you're worried about "pandering," but I think that sending a thank-you email after any interview is generally recommended.

Sending one that also mentions how much you appreciated their code review and *"oh by the way, I fixed the last part of the coding test, feel free to check it out on the same repo we were using"* is just icing on the cake. Even if it doesn't get you *this job* it's a pretty good way to make sure they remember you, should any other positions open up there in the future.

Comment: spot-on language here.

Comment: I have another non-technical interview with them before a decision is made. Ok, I will definitely follow up on this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rurp following up shows them that you are able to take constructive criticism and turn it into something useful. This is exactly what you'll be doing pretty much every day on the job. And if there's a second round, of course you should complete the assignment. It might even be that it was designed so you'd not pass it in the first round. Time constraints in those assignments are usually meant to make people nervous and not deliver the full thing. Following up is only natural.